# React firebase mobile OTP authentication issue : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'verify')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

I am really stuck on this firebase mobile OTP authentication.

I'm getting undefined value in verify in recaptcha. This is my first time implementing this and google changed their SDK to version 9 making searching for resources even more difficult.

I tried everything I could but could not come up with the solution.
[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQH3r.png)

Code:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";
// import { firebaseApp, auth } from "./firebase";
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {
  getAuth,
  RecaptchaVerifier,
  signInWithPhoneNumber
} from "firebase/auth";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: ""
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
auth.languageCode = "it";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState();

  const handelChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  };

  const configureCaptcha = () => {
    console.log("configurecaptcha working");
    // const auth = getAuth()
    console.log("auth", auth);

    window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
      "sign-in-button",
      {
        size: "invisible",
        callback: (response) => {
          // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
          onSignInSubmit();
          console.log("Recaptcha verified");
        },
        defaultCountry: "IN"
      },
      auth
    );
  };

  const onSignInSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    configureCaptcha();

    const phoneNumber = "+91" + state.mobile;
    console.log(phoneNumber);
    const appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;

    console.log("appVerifier", appVerifier);

    signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
      .then((confirmationResult) => {
        // SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message, then sign the
        // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).
        window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
        console.log("OTP has been sent");

        // ...
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Error; SMS not sent
        // ...
        console.log("sms not send");

        console.log(error);
        // console.log(appVerifier);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>login form </h2>
      <form onSubmit={onSignInSubmit}>
        {/* <div id="sign-in-button"></div> */}
        <input
          type="number"
          name="mobile"
          placeholder="Mobile number"
          required
          onChange={handelChange}
        />
        <button type="submit" id="sign-in-button">
          submit
        </button>
      </form>

      <h2>Enter OTP </h2>
      <form>
        <input type="number" name="otp" placeholder="OTP number" required />
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I am also faced with this issue. @Ankur did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still stuck on this issue, this error means that you are initializing the captcha verifier before Auth is ready. Try initializing the verifier after the user selects the MFA option, but before it is used in `phoneInfoOptions`.

Angular example:

```js
// Using @angular/fire 7.5.0
// For more details, see https://github.com/angular/angularfire/tree/master/samples/advanced

// somewhere in the component declaration:
recaptchaVerifier: RecaptchaVerifier | undefined;
resolver: MultiFactorResolver | undefined;

// Inside the constructor:
getRedirectResult(this.auth).then(
      async (result) => {
        if (result && result.user && result.providerId) {
          // This is the signed-in user
          const user = result.user;
          const credential = OAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
          const token = credential?.accessToken;
        } else {
          this.loading = false;
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        const email = error.email;
        if (error.code === 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential') {
          fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(this.auth, email).then((providers) => {
            // TODO - tell user they need to sign in before linking this account
          });
        }
        if (error.code === 'auth/multi-factor-auth-required') {
          this.resolver = getMultiFactorResolver(this.auth, error);
          this.hints = this.resolver.hints as any;
          this.loading = false;
        }
      }
    );

// Pass in the user-selected hint here
async chooseMfaOption(mfa: MultiFactorInfo) {
    this.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
      'recaptcha-container',
      {
        size: 'invisible',
      },
      this.auth
    );
    // Send verification code.
    const phoneInfoOptions = {
      multiFactorHint: mfa,
      session: this.resolver!.session,
    };
    // Only 'phone' is supported at this time
    if (mfa.factorId == 'phone') {
      const provider = new PhoneAuthProvider(this.auth);
      this.verificationId = await provider.verifyPhoneNumber(phoneInfoOptions, this.recaptchaVerifier!);
    } else {
      alert("Selected factor is not supported yet.");
    }

    // Do the rest of your UI updates here
  }
  
  // finish it
  completeMfa(code: string) {
    const phoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
      this.verificationId,
      code
    );
    const multiFactorAssertion =
      PhoneMultiFactorGenerator.assertion(phoneAuthCredential);
    this.resolver
      ?.resolveSignIn(multiFactorAssertion)
      .then(() => console.log('logged in'));
  }
```